# Django - Custom for loop on ModelForm select field raises 'invalid choice' error

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django forms with a RadioSelect widget for one of the fields - `field1`. 
Rendering the form in the template as `{{ form.field1 }}` doesn't raise any errors (i.e. not an invalid choice), but I want to add a little bit more customisation to the radio select widget.

The following code is the general for loop that I'm writing in my template to loop over each choice to style them...

```
{% for choice in acc.field1 %}
    <label>
         <div class='...'><input type='radio' name='field1'/></div>
         <div class='...'>{{ choice }}</div>
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

...which raises the error 'invalid choice'.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: You should look into crispy-forms package to make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what specifically you are trying to render in your two `div`s, but in any case you are missing a `value` attribute on the input that you are rendering manually. Rendering `{{ choice }}` will also render a second input which will further complicate things.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect) for how to control rendering of choices - I think you need to do something along these lines:

```
{% for choice in acc.field1 %}
    <label>
         <!-- Render the input itself -->
         <div class='...'>{{ choice.tag }}</div>
         <!-- Render a label for the input manually -->
         <div class='...'>{{ choice.choice_label }}</div>
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```